# Contactless non-ferrous metals hardening?

Tags: metallurgy

Is it possible to work-harden non-ferrous metals without direct contact?
I know induction hardening is used on ferrous metals, but would like to know if a technique exists for non-ferrous metals.

Comment: Depends on which non-ferrous alloys. Induction hardening (IH) isn't work hardening (WH). IH is the application of a electric field to produce heat which raises it the austenitic temperature which quickly cools to martensite. W H is the application of mechanical work to move the material along its stress-strain curve so that its yield strength is higher.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=o-YTN9aXAeIC&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&dq=non+ferrous+alloy+showing+martensite+structure&source=bl&ots=sNzLxrp5PF&sig=crkye7yrKb3m65JpZkdKQHTaagg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VHJDVZSrNdOJuwTy0IHACg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=non%20ferrous%20alloy%20showing%20martensite%20structure&f=false) link I could find a few non-ferrous systems which show quench-induced or stress-induced martensite . Generally non-ferrous systems dont show this behaviour and they are hardened/strengthened by [Precipitation hardening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precipitation_hardening), [work hardening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_hardening), [Solid Solution Strengthening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_solution_strengthening).

Also work hardening is basically working/deforming the material plastically to strengthen it. So you can't work harden a material without contact. Induction hardening is used mainly for [Case Hardening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_hardening) which is different from hardening(done to bulk of the material). So as long as the non-ferrous alloy is conductive and resistive , Induction hardening is enough for case-hardening.

And if it is hardening , the above mentioned methods are used for non-ferrous. Only the quenching/martensitic transformation is limited to limited systems.